# Appending to already instantiated numpy array is not updated

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say I have the following code, where I am trying to append a numpy array with new values. Since the array is already instantiated to another class, appending to the existing array in one class doesn't update the other.

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

    def init(self):
        self.A = np.zeros((1, 5))

    def add_items(self, item):
        # np.append(self.A, item)
        self.A = np.vstack([self.A, item])
        print "from class A"
        print self.A

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
        self.C = C()

    def init(self):
        self.A.init()
        self.C.init(self.A.A)

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

    def init(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def disp(self):
        print "from class C"

        print self.A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.init()
    b.C.disp()
    b.A.add_items(np.ones((1, 5)))
    b.C.disp()
```

output:

```
from class C
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
from class A
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
from class C
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

please help me, how can I update the attribute A in class C after the attribute A in class A is updated.

Comment: The `def init(self):` type methods just seem to add a chain of redundant calls that makes this more difficult to follow than it needs to be. Why can't it be handled in `__init__`?

Comment: @roganjosh yeah true, in my original problem I need to call a method multiple times in class C with updated attributes in Class A. So it wouldn't be good to instantiate the class multiple times. Please me in achieving my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the object A to C instead of the array A.A to C, it still is connected (be sure to call A.A instead of A when asking for the matrix) (I know this is confusing, but just check the code and you'll understand)

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

    def init(self):
        self.A = np.zeros((1, 5))

    def add_items(self, item):
        # np.append(self.A, item)
        self.A = np.vstack([self.A, item])
        print "from class A"
        print self.A

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
        self.C = C()

    def init(self):
        self.A.init()
        # send self.A instead of self.A.A
        self.C.init(self.A)

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

    def init(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def disp(self):
        print "from class C"
        # now as self.A is an object, and you want the array, return self.A.A
        print self.A.A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.init()
    b.C.disp()
    b.A.add_items(np.ones((1, 5)))
    b.C.disp()
```

this prints:

```
from class C
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
from class A
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
from class C
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Comment: @Nathan I know this would work, but the attributes in class C are different than class A.  I need to abstract class A in class C, also I need to only few attributes from class A in class C to processed in class C. So this solution is not I expected.